# How can I get id to create voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get ID to create a voice channel in discord js v12.

I get an undefined array.

```
server.channels.create('helicopter', {
                                        type: "VOICE",
                                        parent: id_par
}).then( result => { console.log(result.id); voiceID.push(result.id)})
```

I also tried:

```
const newChannel = server.channels.create('helicopter', {
    type: "VOICE",
    parent: id_par
});
let x = await newChannel.id;
```

Here **x** is also *undefined*

And here also:

```vb
server.channels.create('sky', {
                                    type: "VOICE",
                                    parent: id_par
        });
id = server.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'sky' && channel.type === "voice");
voiceID.push(id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GuildChannelManager#create()` returns a **Promise** meaning we're able to use a `.then()` function on it and get the channel object directly after the bot finishes completing this method. After getting the channel object, we can simply take its ID and push it into our desired array.

#### Final Code

```
guild.channels.create('name here', {
  type: 'voice',
  parent: id_par
}).then(channel => voiceID.push(channel.id))
```